# Including FLTK into Eclipse (Neon) CDT project with MinGW

Tags: mingw, eclipse-cdt, building, fltk, eclipse-neon

I'm having trouble with building a basic application with FLTK in C++. I started a project in Eclipse (Neon) CDT and changed the build settings to properly include and recognize the library within my code.

The GCC C++ compiler command:

```
g++ -I<path_to_fltk> -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -fpermissive
```

The GCC Assembler command:

```
as -I<path_to_fltk>
```

The MinGW C++ Linker command:

```
g++ -L<path_to_fltk> -lfltk -lXext -lX11 -lm
```

All of these commands setup the includes for my source code, but whenever I build the project (even after cleaning it) with some [demo code](http://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/basics.html#basics_writing), the executable doesn't get generated and thus the project can't be run and gives a 'Binary not found' error.

I've tried activating some other binary parsers but with no success. Also, I read the article about compiling with FLTK and it said something about libraries ('fltk.lib' and others) which it came with, but I didn't see anything...

So, now I'm thinking: **Where the heck are these libraries? And how do I link them?**

Edit:

The eclipse build output:

```
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lfltk
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lXext
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lX11
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Hi, can you please provide output from Build Console. That will enable us to see error messages and exact commands passed to g++.

Comment: Your -L parameter should be <path_to_fltk>/lib

Comment: @cup In <path_to_fltk>/lib directory there's only 'README.lib' file for some reason...

Comment: How have you obtained FLTK?  Did you get prebuilt libs or did you get the source package from the site?  If you got the source package then you need to build it first.  The older distributions had solutions for visual studio and apple.  I don't know if they now have a solution for eclipse.  If they don't, you probably need to get cmake and run the configuration followed by a make.

Comment: To build FLTK on CDT have a look at https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/157118/  The answer has a step by step guide on what to do.

Comment: How do you expect `-lXext -lX11` on Windows? (even if it is actually on Linux using Wine)