# FLTK GUI not working in eclipse-cdt ide for compiling code

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, fltk

Hi i am a beginner to c++ and i use eclipse ide and i need to use FLTK(1.3.2) in a project and i used a installer to install FLTK( [downloaded from here](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/csep557/14au/tools/fltk_install.html)) on my PC and the location it installed it is: **C:\Program Files\fltk-1.3.2** but when i want to compile any code with FLTK libraries in it, it does not even build it and it gives me error for headers: `fltk/Window.h: No such file or directory`.

i searched a lot and i did not find anything useful i think it has something to do with linker and i need to add libraries to eclipse but i tried everything past 2 days and i could not find a solution.i found these and i did what was in these but it gave me same error message.

[1](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/157118/)

[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39818941/including-fltk-into-eclipse-neon-cdt-project-with-mingw)

[3](https://www.fltk.org/doc-2.0/html/example1.html)

if anyone can help, please help me because i am losing it trying to make this work.

Comment: For starters, the https://www.fltk.org/doc-2.0/html/example1.html document shows a tiny FLTK 2.0 application. You have downloaded FLTK 1.3.2 on your machine, so you need an appropriate FLTK 1.3 code - https://www.fltk.org/doc-1.4/basics.html

Comment: As a beginner you should IMHO not try to follow instructions that are more than 8 years old and try to install such old software as FLTK 1.3.2. The current release is 1.3.8 which you can download as source from https://www.fltk.org/software.php. Instructions for building FLTK from source can be found in our official documentation (https://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/index.html) and several README.*.txt in the root directory of the sources. If you have questions, please ask in our Google Group https://groups.google.com/g/fltkgeneral . This should get you going with FLTK. Have fun!